# Custom style css doesn't work in Gutenberg preview

Tags: block-editor

I added custom CSS file to Wordpress blocks with `add_editor_style( '/css/posts.css' );`. The problem is this style doesn't work for mobile and tablet preview in Gutenberg Editor. Because Im using Kadence Blocks plugin, I've tried to add additional CSS selector with `body.kadence-preview-width-mobile` class but it's doesn't work. So what should I do to makes Gutenberg mobile preview works with custom CSS styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_editor_sytle` adds callback for custom TinyMCE editor stylesheets. and you want to style blocks in block editor, not TinyMCE editor.
use `wp_register_style` and it is by default enqueue to all media screens.
then register this style for any block you want to style using `register_block_style`.
try something like this:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    wp_register_style('awp-block-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom-block-style.css', false);
    register_block_style('core/heading', [
        'name' => 'colored-bottom-border',
        'label' => __('Colored bottom border', 'txtdomain'),
        'style_handle' => 'awp-block-styles'
    ]);
});
```

This way is better because the styled will be enqueued only if block is being used. but if you want to style all blocks at once. then use `wp_enqueue_style` with and hook it to `enqueue_block_editor_assets` for only the editor, and `wp_enqueue_scripts` for the frontend.

you can also style blocks or elements in `theme.json` file.

Comment: Thanks! But in this example, you are created secondary style in block settings, but I don't want to create it - I just want to style the default look.

Comment: Below the example, is how to change default. Or overwrite it.

Comment: Found it, thanks for help!